# My Command-line prompt says "7%" instead of showing the path (usually ~/$)

Tags: zsh

Since this morning, when I open an iTerm or regular Terminal the command prompt looks like this (I also added the command to show my OSX version) :

```
Last login: Thu Mar  3 15:48:56 on ttys000
7% sw_vers -productVersion
10.10.5
7%
```

It always used to be something like

```
~$
```

(I don't even remember but it wasn't `7%` that's for sure). What does it mean ?

Comment: What does `printf "%s\n" "$PS1"` show?

Comment: Weirdly enough, the problem disapeared after I rebooted my computer...

Comment: @chepner: It did it again, this time it shows "pc71%". I had run your command before the bug came again and have re-runned it just now, It looks like the same output to me : %m%#

Comment: `%m` is the host name in the prompt, while `%#` just shows either a `%` or `#`, depending on what level of privileges the current user has (usually, `#` for root and `%` for a normal user). If the value of `PS1` is the same before and after the change in prompt, then you are likely seeing the effects of something like DHCP changing your host name. If the value of `PS` itself is changing, I would try to pay attention to what commands you are running at the prompt; perhaps you are sourcing a file that updates your prompt. (Python's `virtualenv` does this via its activation script, for example.)

Comment: Thanks ! Do you have any idea how I can make sure ? Or how I could cleanup my shell ?